# DevExpress XtraReports server side filtering

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying out DevExpress XtraReports and I have a simple report with a few filter conditions and parameters passed via the front end application. I want to know is this filter appended to the SQL generated and evaluated server side (efficient) or is the filter performed client side once the data has been returned? If it is done client side I will need to convert the reports to use stored procs or else they will be too inefficient on large data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XtraReports Suite supports two different filtration kinds: client side and server side.  All these options are described in our documentation at:

[Filtering Data](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument1184)

So, you can implement the server side filtration.  Please also refer to the [How to: Filter Data at a Data Source's Level](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4804) topic.

Comment: This is useful. Ended up setting stored proc at runtime.